# Using underscore and period with XPath

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xpath, xml-namespaces

I need to select a node which has attribute `name` as `_1.1.1`

I am trying to select the node as

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("IKS", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/objects");    
XmlNode xRootNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//folder[@name='Global']");
```

But it doesn't return any. I'm sure its because of the special characters in my expression. How should I handle it to get the desired node?

**EDIT**: I access node as

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("IKS", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/objects");    
XmlNode xRootNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//folder[@name='Global']", nsmgr);
```

and the XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workplace xmlns='IKS:'>
  <cabinet name='Groups%20and%20Departments' oid='_1.25.18'>
    <folder name='Global' oid='_1.11.9882'></folder>
  </cabinet>
</workplace>
```

Comment: No, there's nothing problematic or special about the value `_1.1.1`. If you remove the `[@name='_1.1.1']` part from the XPath, does it successfully select anything? Can you show us your XML?

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that your XML has a namespace defined and you did not honor that.

Comment: @Tomalak I was looking at that only but it is still not helping me.

Comment: @Tomalak childnodes is getting me the nodes, but selectsinglenode isnt.

Comment: Look for `xmlns` declarations in your XML and then search for `XMLNamespaceManager` here on SO. For example [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271689/), one of literally more than a thousand that all point out the same thing.

Comment: @Saksham Is there a reason you have ignored my plea to see your XML?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XPath not working correctly with XFA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460688/xpath-not-working-correctly-with-xfa)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close to having the correct approach. You have declared a namespace prefix, but you need to actually use it:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("IKS", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/objects");    
XmlNode xRootNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//IKS:folder[@name='Global']");
//                                             ^^^^------- here
```

Note: For some reason, you have `xmlns="IKS:"` in your XML. If that is in fact what your XML looks like, then `IKS:` is the namespace URI you need to use:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("IKS", "IKS:");    
XmlNode xRootNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//IKS:folder[@name='Global']");
```

Comment: @Saksham You're not using it. You have `//folder` where you should have `//IKS:folder`.

Comment: Ohh. I tried adding it before but accidentally removed it. you are GOD!!

Comment: @Saksham No, you are just not through enough.